# How to run schtasks commands/.cmd batch file in Windows terminal (not run as administrator)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-task-scheduler

Open a windows terminal and run as administrator, I can run schtasks commands successfully without type in username and password.

But if I double click cmd to open a windows terminal (not run as administrator), I got access deny error. In this case, how can I run schtasks to create a task in task scheduler? Or run a .cmd batch file that has schtasks commands?
Is it possible to type in admin or the current login username and password to run the commands?

Answer (score 0):

From `schtasks /create /?`. The first set (`/u` and `/p`) is who are you running `schtasks` program as. The second set (`/ru` and `/rp`) is what the task should run as. `/U` and `/P` are available in all sub commands.

```
/U   username      Specifies the user context under which SchTasks.exe
                   should execute.

/P   [password]    Specifies the password for the given user context.
                   Prompts for input if omitted.

/RU  username      Specifies the "run as" user account (user context)
                   under which the task runs. For the system account,
                   valid values are "", "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
                   or "SYSTEM".
                   For v2 tasks, "NT AUTHORITY\LOCALSERVICE" and
                   "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE" are also available as well
                   as the well known SIDs for all three.

/RP  [password]    Specifies the password for the "run as" user.
                   To prompt for the password, the value must be either
                   "*" or none. This password is ignored for the
                   system account. Must be combined with either /RU or
                   /XML switch.
```